# Grails - Dynamically assign table to search from

Tags: grails

Basically what I'm trying to do is receive the name of one of my tables as a string and then search from that table. What I've tried so far (neither of which works):

```
params.tableName.findById(100)
```

AND:

```
def tables = grailsApplication.domainClasses
def table
tables.each {
    if(it.name.toString() == params.tableName) {
        table = it
    }
}
table.findById(100)
```

I realise that the description of my question is a little short which is mostly because it was rather hard to explain and I'm hoping that the code examples I'm giving will make up for it but if it's too vague, let me know and I'll try to be more clear. Also, I'm working in Grails 2.2.5 so answers that'll work for this version will be most appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `"${params.tableName}".findById(100)` provided `params.tableName` is the proper Domain class (e.g. if the domain is called MyThing then the value is exactly that)?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't make a difference, it threw the same error as when I only did `params.tableName.findBy...`. I don't entirely understand the second part of your question, but if you're asking whether or not `params.tableName` is set to a correct table name that actually exists, then yes, `params.tableName` does return a correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up doing the trick was the following:

```
def table = grailsApplication.getClassForName("path.to.package.${params.tableName}")
def record = table.get(100)
println record // successfully prints the record and as such I'm assuming it works
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how sensible this is but the following works for me:

```
def id = Eval.me( "your.domain.package.${params.tableName}.findById( 100 )" )
```

Comment: Are you using `groovy.util.Eval`? Because I just tried it and it's giving me an error saying that it doesn't recognise the package that my table is in.

Comment: Yes, works a treat, do you have the final period before the class name maybe?